# WFFM Custom Error Message

Tags: wffm

We've built a register form inside WFFM with a custom save action.  The custom save action tries to create a new user with an exterior service.  However sometimes the e-mail they use to register, already exists in the exterior service.

When a user registers with an account that's already in use, we would like to display a message at the top where the usual error message that says: "There was a problem while trying to register your account".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a custom form verification action, similar to your custom save action.  Look at WFFM > settings > actions > form verification > user exists for a model to follow.  The error messaging is part of the form verification action
[image]